# Thread in java bean

Tags: java, multithreading, jsp, session, javabeans

I have a session bean in JSP, and in that bean I am starting a thread that sleeps for 10 sec and executes again. The problem I am facing is, after logging out also this thread continues to run.

Can someone please help how to stop that from running?

Comment: Call the session bean from js every 10s. If you logout the js wont call it any more.

Comment: invoking threads inside your jsp would likely make your app behave unpredicatably. why do you want to invoke the thread

Comment: it is not jsp where i am invoking thread. I have polling in my JSP file which reads data from that bean, so for reading the data from backend i have to start a thread in bean.. But after logging out also this thread is running/

Comment: The thread will run because your bean will be in memory. If this is EJBs you are using then i would propose using the TimerService.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [EJB specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/ejb-3.1-pfd-oth-JSpec/), starting threads from EJBs is illegal. Cf. section 21.2.2 (page 593):

> "The enterprise bean must not attempt to manage threads. The enterprise bean must not attempt to start, stop, suspend, or resume a thread, or to change a thread’s priority or name. The enterprise bean must not attempt to manage thread groups."

There may be a different solution using EJB or you may need to use a different framework. This depends on what exactly you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Starting threads out of servlets is not a good idea because you may ran out of resources (memory and CPU) if you have many users. Especially with database access strange behaviour will occur!

Add a Quartz timer (http://quartz-scheduler.org) that triggers every 10secs and processes a list where your session beans have beed subscribed. On user logout unsubscribe your bean from your service again.